# Ion-Ion Scale Capacitance

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, coulombs-law, ions

Ions have three dimensions in solution and can be estimated as spheres. If ions have dimensions they can experience some degree of capacitance, e.g. an electrostatic potential which increases linearly with distance according to Ohm's law given the fixed charge of individual ions. This capacitance would influence an ion's electrostatic potential gradient if the local field (distribution of ions in space) was asymmetric (which is statistically the most common configuration of matter).

This capacitive effect is functionally similar to the flux tube of a gluon field, in that it increases linearly with distance. In addition, just as gluon fields maintain color confinement, the ion capacitance may maintain charge neutrality in solutions and materials. Ion scale capacitance may also explain a number of other anomalous phenomena of ions that are generally glossed over.

These capacitive electrostatics are not covered by Coulomb's law. Which like other inverse square laws assumes point charges and interface across a surface of a radially defined sphere. Coulombic electrostatics fall off with distance rather than increasing.

Has the capacitance of individual ion pairs never been considered? I can't find this in the Chemistry literature. Is this discussed in the Physics literature using specific language?